# numpy sort top bottom

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, scipy

I am trying to pull the top 5%, bottom 5% and the remaining out into separate arrays and save the average. My code is below.

```
    tg = 48000000 element float array
    tg.sort()
    pct = int(tg.size*0.05)
    high5 = tg[-pct:].mean()
    low5 = tg[:pct].mean()
    mid90 = tg[pct:-pct].mean()
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to speed this up.

Comment: The vast majority of the time is taken in the `sort` call. This is a fairly optimal algorithm so the basic answer is you may not be able to speed this up. You may be able to get away with something like ['partition'](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html#numpy.partition).

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to fully sort your array. You could just use partition method:

```
tg = 48000000 element float array    
pct = int(tg.size*0.05)

tg.partition([pct, tg.size - pct]) 

mean_low5 = tg[:pct].mean()
mean_high5 = tg[-pct:].mean()
mean_mid90 = tg[pct:-pct].mean()
```

(code was updated according to Jaime' comment)

Comment: this is a great idea (+1)

Comment: `np.partition` can take an array of positions, i.e. you can do `tg.partition([pct, tg.size-pct])` and not have to worry about the secon call to partition scrambling the result of the previous one. And you could of course also do `tg[pct:].partition(tg.size - 2*pct)` in your second call to avoid the scrambling of the first call's result.